# Is there a difference between ℝ and ℙ?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I'm not sure if ℙ is conventional notation for the set of irrational numbers but that's what I'm using it for now. What is the difference between ℝ and ℙ? ℝ∖ℙ = ∅ no?

Comment: is a rational number an irrational one?

Comment: 1) $\mathbb{P}$ is usually used for prime numbers or projective spaces. 2) Do you know the definition of an irrational number? It answers your question immediately.

Comment: @lisyarus: The use of $\Bbb P$ depends very much on the mathematical context. In the contexts with which I’m most familiar, it usually represents the irrationals (when it’s used at all).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Didn't know there's such a notation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Irrational" numbers are commonly defined as the real numbers who are not rational. So with your notation you would have $\mathbb{R} = \mathbb{P} \cup \mathbb{Q}$ or, more commonly, $\mathbb{P}$ is denoted as $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: I got it now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The set of real number is the union of the rationals and the irrationals. Therefore you have :
$$
\mathbb{R} = \mathbb{Q}\ \cup \ \mathbb{P} \\
\mathbb{Q}\ \cap \ \mathbb{P} = \emptyset
$$
Note also that $\mathbb{P}$ usually denotes the set of prime numbers. But here I used it as you defined it.

Comment: The use of $\Bbb P$ depends on the mathematical context. In the contexts with which I’m most familiar, $\Bbb P$ usually denotes the set of irrational numbers.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh ok, I've never come across this notation. Sorry.

Comment: @Zubzub: No problem.